# Why are symmetrical structures highly stable?

Tags: general-relativity, forces, symmetry, supersymmetry, stability

What makes symmetrical structures(geometry) highly stable?

It is perfect to say that the forces acting on a symmetrical structure is balanced and hence stable. But why is it so? To be more specific, *why is sphere the most stable structure(geometry)?*

There is also the concept of symmetry in atomic level or molecular levels where the atomic orbitals are symmetrical.

Also what does symmetry in physics theories mean? like Spacetime symmetries or Supersymmetry. Why are these symmetric?

Comment: Nothing makes symmetrical structures stable. A cube is a very unstable design that should be avoided at all cost. Spheres have very hard to suppress rotational degrees of freedom. That makes them ideal for ball bearings, but you wouldn't want to build your house on a bunch of spheres... every symmetry axis or plane is a mechanical failure mode waiting to happen... as you can see with most crystals that cleave and split easily along these planes.

Comment: @CuriousOne That's true. But why cube is a very unstable?

Comment: Because of the symmetry. Shear forces do not change any of the lengths of the cube, so all the forces that act parallel to the edges are being converted into torques at the corners. That's a bad configuration. The cubic symmetry alone doesn't guarantee strength, it takes a little more than just symmetry. Moreover, one can achieve strong structures without any symmetry, at all, that's what closed cell foams do.

Comment: Stuff like supersymmetry doesn't really have anything to do with the symmetry in our common sense notion.....loosely speaking, the particles in supersymmetry were introduced as 'symmetric' partners to other particles in the standard model to interact with them, and avoid any confrontation with the higg's boson in order to keep it light

Comment: Maybe you would get a better idea of the relation between stability and symmetry from this- symmetric configurations are basically the extrema of potential, but only a local minima would mean an extremely stable configuration. However, this DOES NOT guarantee a global minima(absolute stability);  it merely offers places to look for such global minimas ...... fundamentally, these are  what physics seeks to find.

Comment: There's a reason why you don't see blocks of dirt like in minecraft.  Gravity and erosion make quick work of a block of dirt, always tending to revert to a state of higher entropy and more stable state.